# Are block timestamps decentralized?

Tags: mining, timestamp, protocol

One thing I don't understand about the Ethereum protocol is how timestamps work. If I, as miner, have a reason to fiddle with timestamps (such as adding a few minutes to decrease the mining difficulty) I simply produce a block with a timestamp which is a few minutes larger than the current UNIX time.

I suppose that this is not possible, but I don't understand how this is enforced. Does the network simply not allow blocks which have a drift time which is too large compared to the current time? Or is there some kind of protocol in place which disencourages miners to create invalid timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all the nodes operate on their local time (i.e. the local time of the computer they are being run on) large differences in time between nodes are not allowed. If you are really out of sync with an NTP server, you will experience problems with syncing blocks, consensus, etc. So while not strictly enforced, it is necessary to have accurate local time.

As for the attack you are describing, Ethereum has some checks in place:

- In [PoW (Ethash)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0c5f8c078abca7dc5954e30f307495a5c41c5f6c/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L248) your block will be accepted if you are 15 seconds ahead (or less). If you are trying to propagate a block with a stale timestamp, the block will be instantly rejected.

```
var (
...
allowedFutureBlockTime    = 15 * time.Second
...
)
...
if header.Time > uint64(time.Now().Add(allowedFutureBlockTime).Unix()) {
    return consensus.ErrFutureBlock
}
...
...
if header.Time <= parent.Time {
    return errZeroBlockTime
}
```

- In [PoA (Clique)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0c5f8c078abca7dc5954e30f307495a5c41c5f6c/consensus/clique/clique.go#L252) nodes don't get any leeway to propagate "blocks from the future".

```
// Don't waste time checking blocks from the future
if header.Time > uint64(time.Now().Unix()) {
    return consensus.ErrFutureBlock
}
```

So to summarise: you are absolutely right about the network not allowing blocks that have a delta in time that is too large.

**Edit. Clarification from comments: it's really all about the majority of clients (the 51%). If the majority of clients disable dagger-hashimoto (PoW) block verification you can propagate bogus blocks, etc. So it's essential for clients to operate on the same protocol - this ensures consensus between all of them.**

Comment: True, but this is an implementation in the client. I cannot try to create bogus blocks because I do not have enough mining power, but the mined blocks have no "decentralized level" of enforcement of the timing - it is just that clients are expected to have this implementation, but if the majority of the clients throw this requirement out of the window we can start seeing bogus timestamps while we cannot see bogus blocks regarding their contents which are unrelated to timestamps (due to PoW).

Comment: You are absolutely right, but decentralization is essentially just a bunch of clients talking to each other. If the majority of clients agree on something it becomes the truth (it's not that dramatic of course, but close). The majority also decides on chain reorgs and thus the canonical blocks, and thus transaction history, and thus balances and contract states. It's just the nature of blockchain - it should be susceptible to 51% attacks or else it's not decentralized (this is dangerously close to a personal opinion, but at least it's true in PoW).

Comment: "if the majority of the clients throw this requirement out of the window we can start seeing bogus timestamps while we cannot see bogus blocks regarding their contents which are unrelated to timestamps (due to PoW)" If _your_ client throws this requirement out the window, then it will accept blocks with arbitrary timestamps. Similarly, if your client decides it doesn't care about PoW being correct, then you can see "bogus blocks" in that regard. There's no difference between the two requirements. They're both checked by each node, and a node will refuse to accept invalid blocks.

Comment: Hmm yes this is a good point. So basically these timestamps are enforced on the network because a miner can assume that >50% of the nodes do not accept bogus timestamps. Hence their bogus block does not get accepted by the majority of nodes so they can never payout their mining income @smarx ?

Comment: @IvanAndrusenko I think the main point I learned from here is that in the end it is about the majority of clients accepting blocks which follow a certain protocol. Could you add something like that to your answer? I think more people will think about it this way. The only thing that is odd is that you can essentially verify everything on the chain that no one has tampered with it - except that you cannot check if all nodes have behaved "right" in the past regarding these timestamps because there is no way to actually verify if it was that time at that point.

Comment: You _can_ verify the timestamps. The rule enforced by clients about timestamps is how far they are from the timestamp of the previous block. You can verify that whenever you want.